# Use S3Reader2 plugin as API

Tags: imageresizer

Can you provide an example of using the S3Reader2 plugin with ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build?

I would like to output an S3 image through Response.Output / Response.Write

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending the output to Response, then you should use the URL API instead; writing your own handler will introduce a lot of issues.

That said, it's easy to use the S3 plugin from .Build. Just provide a virtual path like so:

`ImageBuilder.Current.Build("~/s3/mybucket/myfile.jpg", outstream, instructions);`

Comment: Simple and efficient - thnx!

Comment: One additional question. I have diskcache enabled for S3 URL API so I was wondering if the above approach works with diskcache?